# Are multiple amp-ad nodes allowed?

Tags: amp-html

I have an AMP page with two  nodes, but only one seems to render.

```
<amp-ad width="300" height="250" type="doubleclick" data-slot="[DFP Unit]"></amp-ad>
...a bunch of text...
<amp-ad width="300" height="250" type="doubleclick" data-slot="[Same DFP Unit as above]"></amp-ad>
```

Are two amp-ads not allowed in one page? Maybe I have to make different unit names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at an example AMP like: https://amp.theguardian.com/artanddesign/2010/oct/26/eames-furniture-team-charles-ray you will see that it is possible to have arbitrary numbers of amp-ads on a page. You can have as many as you want.

Comment: Wow, thanks you for that example! And they even use the same slot-id for their ads. I now think my issue was just because of the lack of bidders for my test page, or maybe even some AdX or DFP rules.

Comment: Hit enter too soon - Thank you!